# How do I make it so that only the logged in student is only able to view his own grade rather than viewing everyone

Tags: c#, mysql, forms

I am trying to make it so that only the logged in student is able to view his own grade rather than viewing everyone grades.

I am in the process of creating a canvas application that enable a logged in student to view their assignment and grades. I only need the datagridview to show the logged student assignmentt name and grade.

```
 void GridFillGrade()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("ViewAllGrades", con);
            sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dta = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dta);
            stdGrade.DataSource = dta;
           con.Close();
        }
    } 

    private void StudentPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridFillASs();
        GridFillGrade();
    }
```

the "viewAllGrades" is from mysql query

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ViewAllGrades`()
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
FROM  Grades;

END
```

this is the login code

```
 private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i = 0;
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from stdinfotable where Username='" + textuser.Text + "' and Password= '" + textpass.Text + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter dta = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dta.Fill(dt);
        i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

        if(i==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Hide();
            StudentPage f = new StudentPage();
            f.Show();

        }
        con.Close();

    }
```

so I was wondering if I should do something to the login code in order to archive what I am after but I do not know what that something would be. I am sorry I am still new with database it only been 4 month since I have been using MySql.

Comment: I think you need to study how the WHERE clause in an sql SELECT statement works

Comment: First step would be avoiding SQL Injection (via parametrized queries). Second step would be using a WHERE clause in your grades query that would allow you to filter the grades based on the current user logged in.

Comment: what do you mean by using WHERE clause? how i can i implement that ?@bradbury9

Comment: **[SQL Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)**  ...not unlike the WHERE clause you used in the second snippet

Comment: thank you! I now understand it better but how would that help me with what I am trying to accomplish? @NoneoftheAbove

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your Grades table has a key to tie it with stdinfotable.

If so, then your sql query would be

```
SELECT * FROM Grades WHERE Grades.StudentID = 12
```

In which the logged in student has an ID of 12